# Internet fast when sharing via hotspot or tethering but slow on the device itself

Tags: connection-issues, mobile-network, tethering

Yes, I didn't get that backwards. And all I found is "slow tethering", even here this was never asked before. So, here I am!

Internet is slow on the device, but fast for other devices connected to it.
It doesn't look like the fault of some software I'm using (browser, openvpn)

Soooo how in the world? And how in the world do I fix it?

Model: Doogee T5. OS 6.0, Nothing is changed, no root.

Comment: What kind of tethering: USB, Wi-Fi, Bluetooth? How have you observed this slowness: just that pages seem to load slower, or have you run a bandwidth test? TBH, it sounds most likely to be the fault of some software on the phone, such as an ad blocker app.

Comment: Any kind of tethering, and I don't have any network related software AFAIK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have discovered the cause of this problem... the darn chinese brick is riddled with vendor's own poorly written system level adware. It constantly opens connections to it's servers which turns into a DoS attack on the device itself, akin to shooting your neighbor's house with a bazooka through your own door's keyhole. The device's own network gateway is differerent from the gateways for wifi and bluetooth hotspots, so those are unaffected.

Installing a firewall app solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that internet is not slow but it might be that the servers of the apps or sites that you use on phone are not responding that quickly

To identify the problem use your phone's internet in pc by tethering and try downloading a file that you think is giving full or expected download speed, when done just remember the speed and copy link of this download to phone , now try to download this very same file from android from [ADM](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dv.adm) and add new download by pasting that link and start download ( make sure you turn off tethering before this and all other apps that use internet are not running to get best speeds ) let the download run for few minutes to make sure it reaches stable speed and than compare both the pc speed and this android speed and do report back